# Why em unit not working with paragraph tag as parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, flexbox

I have simple p tag having heading I have set the font-size to paragraph tag however when I set the font-size to heading tag in terms of em unit, the changes are not getting reflected for em

```css
p {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Heading<h2>SubHeading</h2></p>
```

However when I change paragraph to div em font size works correctly.
like below

```css
div {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>Heading<h2>SubHeading</h2></div>
```

Why it is behaving like this ?

Comment: Because `h2` are not valid children of `p` tags.  Inspect your snippet output.  The `h2` is being put outside of the `p`